# How should i send 401 and 403 response code in asp.net core web api?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.1, http-status-codes, entity-framework-core-2.1

I need to send 401 and 403 response code while deleting the user. I am trying to use attribute based routing. Response 401 as object (application/json):
{success: false}
Response 403 as object (application/json):
{success: false}

```
[Authorize]
[Route("users/{id}")]
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(Guid id)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new POCContext())
        {
            var entity = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserId == id);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound(new { success = false });
            }
            else
            {
                context.Users.Remove(entity);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return NoContent();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { success = false });
    }
}
```

X

Comment: and what is the issue? what is the result of your code?

Comment: I getting 500 response code. i am using fiddler for testing. Delete method and this is my request.https://localhost:44384/users/62C2428D-9A7B-40F2-94F1-2200C6C064C6.. am i doing right?

Comment: 500 means that there were an exception thrown. You will need to debug the code to see where is it coming from. If you update your question with the details of the error, maybe we can assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

as you're in a controller you can modify the `Response` directly in your method just doing `Response.StatusCode = 401;` like the following:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("users/{id}")]
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(Guid id)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new POCContext())
        {
            var entity = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserId == id);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 401;
                return NotFound(new { success = false });
            }
            else
            {
                context.Users.Remove(entity);
                context.SaveChanges();
                Response.StatusCode = 200;
                return NoContent();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return BadRequest(new { success = false });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to call the Deleteuser with [Authorize] attribute. if i remove the [Authorize] i am getting at debug point.

Comment: the `[Authorize]` is a filterattribute witch deals with the authorization, the question you're asking is not related to it. what is your issue in your main code?

Comment: I need to check for this many response code while deleting a user from database. Response 204 as object (application/json):
{success: true}
Response 400 as object (application/json):
{success: false}
Response 401 as object (application/json):
{success: false}
Response 403 as object (application/json):
{success: false}
Response 404 as object (application/json):
{success: false}
Response 500 as object (application/json):
{success: false}
 how can i implement all this? Help will be appreciated please